# "Sono qui da anni trentuno" versus "Sono qui da anni trentun"

Tags: word-order

Yes, as it is said in a previous answer *Sono qui da trentun anni* is correct, while *Sono qui da trentuno anni* is awkward. Between the following, which one is correct?

> Sono qui da anni trentun.

> Sono qui da anni trentuno.

If both are wrong, can anyone explain why?

Comment: The truncation (*apocope*) can be made only *before* a word. Anyway, people would raise their eyebrows on hearing *sono qui da anni trentuno*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are wrong, but to correct them, it's necessary to know what you want to say.
If you want to say "I'm here (= I live here) for thirty years", then it's *Sono qui da trentun anni*.
If you want to say "I'm here since the 1930s (or, maybe, 1830s)," then it should be *Sono qui dagli anni Trenta*.

Comment: Is the capitalization of "Trenta" the correct form when referring to a decade?

Comment: @d11wtq Generally speaking, yes. The rule is to capitalize the names of centuries and decades of the XX century (I hope you understand that "the 1830s" in my answer was a joke): _il Cinquecento, gli anni Settanta_. Note that the word _anni_ is sometimes omitted, thus, capitalization helps to show that one refers to a specific period. Nonetheless, this rule is often waived recently, especially when referring to the 2000s: I've seen both _gli anni Zero_ and _gli anni zero_, the latter being even more common.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the inversion between *anni* and the number in similar sentences, in formal documents (*La qui presente Rossi Giovanna di anni 41 […].*); sometimes it was used in other contexts for emphasis.

It's not the normal order used in Italian, but I would not call it wrong.

Comment: *Rossi Giovanna, di anni quarantuno* is bureaucratic and you forgot to invert the names. `;-)` In olden times, we were taught at school to say *la base è centimetri tre*, but this disputable, if not wrong, usage is declining.